# How to install packages for shiny-server on ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I recently moved to `ubuntu 14.04 lts with lamp` in order to use `Rstudio`and `shiny-server`. I can run/test my `apps` locally without any problems. However, via Rserver I always get an error that I have some missing packages. Using .`libpaths()`I was able ti find out:

```
   [1] "/home/h/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"             
   [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                    "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Via `sudo su shiny` I found that:

```
    [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
    [3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

So I conluded that I just `install.packages()`into a directory where shiny doesnt have access. After `sudo su shiny` and testing for some libraries that was the fact. So I thought to `sudo su shiny` and `R`. Then I try to `install.packages()` which resulted in:

```
Warning in install.packages("ggplot2") :
 'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n)
```

So I tried `sudo su shiny` and `sudo R` which resulted in:

`shiny@h:/home/h$ sudo R` where I cant login with my account. I do not understand that, given that I was able to perfom all `sudo` before. Is there a way to overwrite that somehow or solve that issue differently?

Comment: Can you try `sudo R -e '.libPaths(.Library);install.packages(...)'` from your regular user account?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for that suggestion. I get the following: `libPaths(.Library);install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> grep -> contrib.url `

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I just had to add the repo to your command. It works!! Great Help!!